# При переключении исчезает содержимое фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Во фрагментах я не спец, многое списал со StartAndroid, и, вероятно, тамошний пример не был рассчитан на мой случай.

Создал layout с несколькими фрагментами. Один фрагмент, ниже второй. Первый фрагмент, опуская ненужные подробности:

```
public class Timer extends Fragment {

    DrawView drawView;    //класс для рисования во фрагменте

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        drawView = new DrawView(getActivity());
        return drawView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Второй фрагмент:

```
public class BelowTimer extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.below_timer, null);
    }
}
```

Основная Activity, в которой происходят транзакции с фрагментами:

```
public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * All fragments on this activity & its utils.
 */
Timer timer;
FillDayRate fillDayRate;
NutrientsRatio nutrientsRatio;
BelowTimer belowTimer;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    timer = new Timer();
    fillDayRate = new FillDayRate();
    nutrientsRatio = new NutrientsRatio();
    belowTimer = new BelowTimer();
}

public void onClickMenu(View view) {
    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.timer:
            Log.d("onClick", "timer");
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_view, timer);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_below_main, belowTimer);
            break;
        case R.id.fill_day_rate:
            Log.d("onClick", "fillDayRate");
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_view, fillDayRate);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_below_main, belowTimer);
            break;
        case R.id.nutrients_ratio:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_view, nutrientsRatio);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_below_main, belowTimer);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

В ней три кнопки. При первом нажатии на любую кнопку отображаются оба фрагмента (верхние фрагменты разные, нижний пока один). При нажатии на любую другую кнопку пропадает отображение первого фрагмента и на его месте ничего уже не появляется, сколько ни нажимай. При повторном нажатии на кнопку, нажатую в первый раз (если никакая другая кнопка не была нажата) — пропадает второй фрагмент, далее при нажатии на любую другую пропадает первый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас выполняется одна `fragmentTransaction`, когда по факту их должно быть две.

Используйте следующий кейс:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.first:
                showFragmentTop(FirstTopFragment.newInstance());
                showFragmentBottom(FirstBottomFragment.newInstance());
                break;
            case R.id.second:
                showFragmentTop(SecondTopFragment.newInstance());
                showFragmentBottom(SecondBottomFragment.newInstance());
                break;
            case R.id.third:
                showFragmentTop(ThirdTopFragment.newInstance());
                showFragmentBottom(ThirdBottomFragment.newInstance());
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    void showFragmentTop(Fragment fragment) {

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.topContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    void showFragmentBottom(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.bottomContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

**Пример фрагмента, на всякий случай**

```
public class FirstTopFragment extends Fragment {


    public static FirstTopFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FirstTopFragment fragment = new FirstTopFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FirstTopFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top, container, false);
    }

}
```

**Дополнительно:**

— Называйте фрагменты по такому типу: `NameFragment`, `SecondNameFragment` и т.д.

— Создавайте фрагменты с помощью `newInstance();`

Comment: Странно, я добавлял ради эксперимента вторую транзакцию, но проблему это не решало. Спасибо, попробую Ваш код.

Comment: Отлично, всё заработало.